# Ansible does not appear to be loading the ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 variable from the inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

When I set the value for ansible_python_interpreter for a host to /usr/bin/python3 ansible-playbook still seems to be using /usr/bin/python which points to python2.7
I get this from the -vvv where the output says

```
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/vmware/vmware_guest.py
```

I put in a debug in my yml file that was to output the variable and it returns:

```
"ansible_python_interpreter": "/usr/bin/python3"

ansible --version
ansible 2.8.2
   config file = /ansible/automation/ansible.cfg
   configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', 
 '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 25 2019, 21:02:35) [GCC 4.8.5 
20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
```

I have shifted the location in the inventory file to be the first variable and I added it as a group variable but no joy.

When I ran the ansible-playbook command with the -e ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 the script ran correctly

Inventory file

`[control] <REDACTED HOST NAME> ansible_connection=local  ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3`

yml excerpt

```
---
   - hosts: control
     gather_facts: false
     tasks:
       - name: Debug a variable
         debug:
           var: ansible_python_intrepreter
       - name: Clone a virtual machine from Windows template and customize
         vmware_guest:
           hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
           username: "{{ username }}"
           password: "{{ password }}"
           validate_certs: no
           datacenter: some-datacenter
           cluster: some-cluster
           folder: "some-folder"
           name: some-host
           template: some-template
           datastore: "some-datastore"
           networks:
           - name: some-network-name
             ip: x.x.x.x
             netmask: 255.255.255.0
             gateway: x.x.x.x
             mac: aa:bb:dd:aa:00:14
             domain: domain.com
             dns_servers:
             - x.x.x.x
             - x.x.x.x
```

When the process runs I get this error
"Failed to import the required Python library (requests) on  Python /usr/bin/python2"

Answer (score 1):

The variables must be in the same line as the host.

```
[control]
REDACTED_HOST_NAME ansible_connection=local ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

It is more convenient to use the group_vars

```
[control]
REDACTED_HOST_NAME
[control:vars]
ansible_connection=local
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

With the *hosts*

```
localhost
[control]
REDACTED_HOST_NAME
[control:vars]
ansible_connection=local
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

the play

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars['REDACTED_HOST_NAME'].ansible_python_interpreter }}"
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "/usr/bin/python3"
}
```

, but with the hosts below

```
localhost
[control]
REDACTED_HOST_NAME ansible_connection=local
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

the same play fails

```
'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'ansible_python_interpreter'
```

Comment: The variables were on one line. For some reason the second variable dropped to the second line when I was putting it into the post. The debug does return as expected it is the rest of the yml that reverts back to python2. I just ran the ansible-playbook command by calling it explicitly from /usr/local/bin and the activity finished successfully. The "which ansible-playbook" command claims it is located in /usr/local/bin so it should be running python3.6. I ran ansible-playbook --version and it returned using python2.7 but if I ran /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook it returns python3.6